# MacBook Pro 13" freezes (blue vertical lines) after upgrade to 8GB

Tags: memory, upgrade, freeze, macbook-pro

I just upgraded my MacBook Pro 13" (Late 2009) **from 2GB RAM to 8GB**. The memory I installed is the Kingston Kit, KTA-MB1066K2/8G.

**Ever since the upgrade, my MacBook freezes at unpredictable moments not long after I start using it. The moment it freezes, both displays show blue vertical lines**, though it happened once without the lines.

Another thing that struck me was that without my 26" 1920 x 1200 external monitor hooked into the MacBook, this freezing hasn't happened thus far.

Also, I flipped one memory card with the original 1GB, resulting in a total of 5GB now. The freezing hasn't happened thus far.

**Is anyone familiar with this faulty behaviour?**

*(Bonus question: is it really that bad to have a 1 and 4 GB card next to each other?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It appears to be bad memory.** I'm returning the chips today.